# Zeros of a nearly holomorphic form

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $f$ be a nearly holomorphic modular form on a Hilbert modular variety $Sh$. Suppose that $f$ vanishes on a Zariski dense subset of CM points on $Sh$. How to show that $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: This is an interesting question even for $GL_2 / \mathbf{Q}$ (where nearly holomorphic modular forms are just polynomials in $E_2$ with coefficients that are modular forms).